# DevExpress XAF ChartList Datetime format

Tags: c#, date, datetime, devexpress, xaf

I'm struggling with DevExpress XAF ChartList, where I need to provide formatting DateTime format for AxisX. Currently, it has format "dd/MM/yyy", but I need "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss". Chart settings wizard hadn't provide such options, in DevExpress documentation I failed to find such solution. Is there any way to format DateTime in AxisX?

P.S.
Is there any general way to format data at axises as I need?

Thanks in an advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the chart wizard go in Axes from the navigation and ensure its on the XAxis, then go down to the Labels tab and select the Auto tab, from the format dropdown select custom and in the format string set dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

[image]